# Array of map values were not populating on page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I have below code in wire method where I need to pass array of map value to html to populate on a list; that is passing the teacher value (which is an array of map values)  to custom type of datatable.

[image]

I am getting the values in the console.log as below

[image]

Below is the full code snippet.

student.html

```
<template>
<c-custom-datatable key-field="id" data={studentList} columns={columns} hide-checkbox-column> </c-custom-datatable>
</template>
```

student.js

```
const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name'},
    { label: 'Class', fieldName: 'class' },
    {label : 'Teacher', fieldName: 'ownershipDetail', type: 'customTeacher', typeAttributes: {teacher : {fieldName : 'teacher'}}},
    { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'status' }
];

export default class StudentTeacherDetails extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

studentList = [];
@api recordId;

@wire(getRecords, {studentId: '$recordId'})
    wiredStudents(result) {  
if(result.data){
let studentAcctArray = [];
result.data.forEach(studentAcct => {
let row = {};
row.name = studentAcct.StudentName__c;
row.class = studentAcct.StudentClass__c;
row.status = studentAcct.StudentStatus__c;
var mapTeacherDetails = new Map();
var teachers = studentAcct.teacher__c.replace("{","").replace("}","").split(',');
var mapToTeacher = [];
var isNetVal = false;
for(var l=0;l.teachers.length;l++){
var temp = teachers[l].trim().split('=');
var mapTeacherDetail = new Map();

if(temp[0] == ''){
mapTeacherDetail.set('isTeacherIdEmpty', true);
}else{
mapTeacherDetail.set('isTeacherIdEmpty', false);
}

if(!isNextVal){
isNextVal = true;
}else{
mapTeacherDetail.set('isOtherrec', true);
}
mapTeacherDetails.set(temp[1], mapTeacherDetail);
}
mapToTeacher.push(mapTeacherDetails);
row.teacher = mapToTeacher;

studentAcctArray.push(row);
});
this.studentList = studentAcctArray;
}
}
}
```

customDatatable.html

```
<template> 
<c-student-teacher teacher={typeAttributes.teacher} >
</c-student-teacher> 
</template>
```

customDatatable.js

```
import customTeacherTemplate from './customTeacher.html';

export default class CustomDatatable extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        customTeacher: {
          template: customTeacherTemplate,
          standardCellLayout: true,
          typeAttributes: [ "teacher"]
        }
      };
}
```

customStudentTeacher.html

```
<template for:each={teacher} for:item="items">
            <template for:each={items.value} for:item="item" for:index="itmx">
                <template if:true={item.isTeacherIdEmpty}>
                    {item.teacherName}
                </template>
                <template if:false={item.isTeacherIdEmpty}>
                    <span onclick={navigateToTeacher} key={item.teacherId} data-record={item.teacherId}>
                        <a href="#">{item.teacherName}</a>
                    </span>
                </template>
            </template>
        </template>
```

customStudentTeacher.js

```
export default class CustomStudentTeacher extends LightningElement {
    @api teacher;
}
```

The values are not populating on the page. Not sure where I was going wrong. Please suggest or correct me. Thank you.

*****Update*****

I was trying to have in the array format but when teacher is passed to customDatatable as typeAttributes it is been passed as object. So tried to convert it into array by below code,

```
this.teachers = Object.entries(this.teacher).map(([key,value])=>({ key, value }));
```

With this I have ended with more looping and even that did not resulted in values.Below is how console.log shows

[image]

Below is customStudentTeacher.html

```
<template for:each={teachers} for:item="items">                
   <template for:each={items.value} for:item="teacher" >                
       <template for:each={teacher} for:item="item">
           {item}
       </template>
    </template>
</template>
```

Is populating all the values like a list as shown below in the column on the page
[image]

On the page it is shown with both key as well as value
[image]

Comment: Please post the full Javascript code

Comment: Added JS code @fred.

Comment: What is `{teacher}` referring to in your HTML? Would help if you provided the full HTML

Comment: updated the questionnaire with code snippet

Comment: I think you should be using standard objects, not maps.

Comment: On observation with console.log in customStudentTeacher "teacher" is an object instead of array, even though it is an array in parent cmp. Due to this it is not looping in the html, how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate a Map in the template. You can't do this.

Simply put, make your data structure like this:

```
teachers = [
             {"isTeacherIdEmpty":false,"teacherName":"Sue",teacherId:"123"},
             {"isTeacherIdEmpty":false,"teacherName":"Jan",teacherId:"123"},
             {"isTeacherIdEmpty":true,"teacherName":"Bob",teacherId:""}
           ];
```

Then, modify your template to be like this:

```
<template for:each={teacher} for:item="teacher">
    <template if:true={teacher.isTeacherIdEmpty}>
        {teacher.teacherName}
    </template>
    <template if:false={teacher.isTeacherIdEmpty}>
        <span onclick={navigateToTeacher} key={teacher.teacherId} data-record={teacher.teacherId}>
            <a href="#">{teacher.teacherName}</a>
        </span>
    </template>
</template>
```

Notice I have one less level of nesting in the template?

Essentially, you need to design your data structure first, then build your UI layer on top. Then it's not a guessing game.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Caspar. I agree code was clumsy but I am trying to find a solution. I tried to make changes as per your suggestion it didnt worked. Even with the existing code we are getting values in console.log and even in customStudentTeacher.js file when I checked with console.log it is returning the data but the data was not getting populated on html. Not sure about the reason.

Comment: changed answer.

Comment: please see the updated code. Still issue exists. Thank you.